# Delphi: Sort ClientDataSet by datetime asc, nulls last

Tags: sorting, delphi, indexing, null, tclientdataset

I need to sort a ClientDataSet by a DateTime field, e.g. `next_due_date`, in ascending order and with null values last.

I will be adding new records at runtime and I **am not allowed to** execute the SQL **query again**.

Can you use an index on a ClientDataSet in such a way?

Comment: You did not specify your database, some SQL's allow you to specify `NULL FIRST/LAST`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12767777/650492

Comment: As usual MySQL uses an undocumented `-` syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8174026/650492

Comment: You can create a calculated field, or for example set to your `next_due_date` field `DefaultExpression` to `DateTimeToStr(MinDateTime)`. Not elegant, but could work (but MIDAS is not elegant too and well, works in some way). I'm saying this because I don't think you can define index in such way.

Comment: @Victoria Thanks, but I think I will use a sql query to get the data initially sorted and simply insert the new records at the right position by moving my cursor as explained here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993382/9658630](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993382/9658630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create internal calculated field in cds, populate it as your needs dictate and create an index referring to that field